# Unable to create instance of MyEntities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm working on a MVC app, which uses Entity Framework.

I added new Ado.Net Entity Data Model file, called Car.

In my web.config file, I have this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyProjectName-20130322132315;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MyProjectName-20130322132315.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="CarEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Car.csdl|res://*/Models.Car.ssdl|res://*/Models.Car.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Car;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

In my controller, I'm trying to do this:

```
CarEntities car_db = new CarEntities();
```

And I get syntax error. CarEntities is unrecognized. The Resolve option isn't there. Why is this happening? I found out that I can get the tables from my db directly. But this doesn't work:

```
int exist = (from x in User where x.username == username select x).Count();
```

The .edmx file is in my Models folder, and in my controller I do have:

```
using MyProjectName.Models;
```

In another solution, I am perfectly able to do this:

```
MyEntities myDatabase = new MyEntities();
(from x in myDatabase.User where x.username == username select x).Count();
```

Comment: You cant create an instance of connectionString ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove these two files:

[image]

and then to set the 'Code Generation Strategy' property to an alternate value. This property is available in the Properties Window when the model is open in the designer.